# Yii2 more than one OR condition

Tags: activerecord, yii2

How can i use more than one OR

```
$data = Info::find()
    ->andFilterWhere(['OR',
        [ 'LIKE', 'username LIKE "%' . $text . '%" '],
        [ 'LIKE', 'name LIKE "%' . $text . '%" '],
        [ 'LIKE', 'data LIKE "%' . $text . '%" '],
        [ 'LIKE', 'skype LIKE "%' . $text . '%" '],
        [ 'LIKE', 'position LIKE "%' . $text . '%" '],
        [ 'LIKE', 'duties LIKE "%' . $text . '%" '],
        [ 'LIKE', 'position_en LIKE "%' . $text . '%" '],
        [ 'LIKE', 'display_name_en LIKE "%' . $text . '%" '],
    ])
    ->asArray()
    ->all();
```

Comment: what query in sql do  you want?

Comment: SELECT * FROM Info WHERE username LIKE %' . $text . '% OR name LIKE %' . $text . '% OR  data LIKE "%' . $text . '% ....

Answer (score 2):

The proper way to use it is:

```
$data = Info::find()
        ->andFilterWhere(['or',
            ['like', 'username', $text],
            ['like', 'name', $text],
            ['like', 'data', $text],
            ['like', 'skype', $text],
            ['like', 'position', $text],
            ['like', 'duties', $text],
            ['like', 'position_en', $text],
            ['like', 'display_name_en', $text],
        ])
        ->asArray()
        ->all();
```

The difference between `andFilterWhere()` and `andWhere()` is that the first one ignores empty query operands.